# The Maschler's bargaining set in the cooperative game theory, missing a step in the proof

Tags: functions, real-numbers, game-theory, boolean-algebra

I have a problem with the concept of the **bargaining set** which is given below in some detail.
Let $N=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ be a set of players and $v:2^N\to \mathbb{R}$
a superadditive game (meaning $S,T \subseteq N ,\,S \cap T=\emptyset \Longrightarrow v(S)+v(T)\le v(S \cup T).$) in coalitional function form.
For $y\in\mathbb{R}^C$ and $S\subseteq N$ write $y(S)$ for $\sum_{i\in C}y_i.$ So $y(\emptyset)=0.$
Write ${\cal S_{kl}}=\{T \subseteq N\,|\,k \in T,\, l \notin T\}.$
Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^D$ be an individually rational imputation with $x(D)=v(D)$.
What is the relationship between the following two formulas-I'd like them to be equivalent $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^C$:

$(\exists D \in {\cal S_{lk}})\big(D \cap C=\emptyset \;\wedge\; x(D)\leq v(D)\big) \quad\vee$
$\Big((\forall i \in C)(y_i > x_i)\quad\wedge$
$(\forall D \in {\cal S_{lk}})\big(x(D \setminus C)+y(D \cap C) > v(D)\big)$
$\ \Longrightarrow \ y(C)>v(C)\Big).$

and

$(\exists D \in {\cal S_{lk}})\big(D \cap C=\emptyset \;\wedge\; x(D)\leq v(D)\big) \quad\vee$
$\Big((\forall i \in C)(y_i \geq x_i)\quad\wedge$
$(\forall D \in {\cal S_{lk}})\big(x(D \setminus C)+y(D \cap C) \geq v(D)\big)$
$\ \Longrightarrow \ y(C)\geq v(C)\Big).$

We may assume that the first part before $\vee$ which is the same in both
is **not** satisfied.
The only difference is by replacing some $>$ with $\geq.$
The problem arises when $D\cap C=\emptyset,$ otherwise they are equivalent by increasing coordinates of $y$ and slight considertaions.
Perhaps here may be used the superadditivity of $v$?

I believe that the second is equivalent to this

$\Big(k,l\in N \;\wedge\; k \neq l \;\wedge\; C \in {\cal S_{kl}} \quad \Longrightarrow$

$(\exists D \in {\cal S_{lk}})\big(D \cap C=\emptyset \;\wedge\; x(D)\leq v(D)\big)\quad\vee$

$ \min\big\{y(C)\,|\, x(D \setminus C) +y(D \cap C) \geq v(D),\,
    D \in {\cal S_{lk}},\, y_i \geq x_i,\, i \in C \big\} \geq  v(C)\Big),$
which is my aim to obtain from the first displayed formula with strict
inequalities which are problematic to obtain these weak inequalities and $\min$. The entire thing here is to obtain weak linear inequalities connected by Boolean connectives that determine the Maschler bargaining set which is a quite interesting concept in cooperative game theory. The formulas are supposed to describe the bargaining set $\cal M$, which is such that there is no justified objection of a player $k$ to $l$. And it is of the form
finite union of polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^N.$

Comment: Your definition seems not to be correct. Can you give a reference of that definition? First of all an objection must have strict inequalities, it must be preferred for each member of $C$. Moreover, you do not have defined a counter-objection. But by the definition of the bargaining set it is required that for each objection exists a counter-objection. Finally, your notation is not consistent, and difficult to read.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt The paper is mine and it can be downloaded from [here](https://uloz.to/file/uSPLfBOlCb57/j-pdf?do=slowDirectDownload). But I'm afraid that you don't know the Czech language in which the paper is written in.But the formulas in it may be self-explanatory.The bargaining set should be a union of polytopes and hence should be determined by weak inequalities at the end.Can you specify which part of my notation is **not** consistent ?

Comment: Please send me the paper by e-mail. The link was blocked. Of course, it is the union of convex polytopes, but I don't see that those are the right ones. As I mentioned, the definition of the counter-objection is missing or a proof that it collapses to this definition here. Moreover, you interchange in the first part $C$ and $S$. Furthermore, at this part the sets $C$ and $D$ are not introduced. Hence, one cannot capture the dimension of the introduced payoff-vectors. Finally, in case that you set $x(D)=v(D)$, it makes not so much sense to claim later on $x(D) \le v(D)$.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt I'll send you the pdf of the paper to your email. Can you please give your email to me? The definition of counter-objection can be found there. There may well be many typos since I've written everything by myself and no one has checked it.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt My result of linear inequalities that determine the bargaining set by my procedure fortunately yielded the same result as given by Michael Maschler: The inequalities that determine the bargaining set. So not everything is wrong in my considerations.

Comment: Please send me the file to "Holger.Meinhardt at wiwi.uni-karlsruhe.de".  Have you checked it out for every bargaining set? Or do you get the same result by combinatorical chance? I will have a look on it, and try to understand it despite my lack in Czech.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt The email has been sent. You may well be right that it is a combinatorial chance.